# how to convert a json-string to a hashtable

Tags: powershell

**How do we convert the json string into a hastable?**
.

Suppose I  have a string such as:

```
{"Application":"Billing Interface","Business Area":"Interfaces","Region":"YO"}
```

How do we convert this to a hash table?

I'm doing this right now:

```
$myJsonString= 
$myJsonString.TrimEnd("}")
             .TrimStart("{")
             .Replace('":"',"= ")
             .Replace('"',"")
             .Replace(","," `n ")
$myJsonString = ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData $myJsonString
```

**How do we convert the json string into a hastable?**

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you need a `Hashtable` specifically, but you could use [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7) to output a `PSCustomObject` and then convert to a hash table (`$hash`).

```
$myjsonstring = '{"Application":"Billing Interface","Business Area":"Interfaces","Region":"YO"}'
$myjsonstring | ConvertFrom-Json | Foreach-Object {
    $hash = @{}
    $_.PSObject.Properties | Foreach-Object {
        $hash.Add($_.Name,$_.Value)
    }
    $hash
}
```

Note that PowerShell Core has the `-AsHashTable` parameter that may work for you if you are running that version.

Answer (score 1):

If you take that json string you have, convert it to an object, you can access the elements by using the name of the element.

```
$JsonString = "{""Application"":""Billing Interface"",""Business Area"":""Interfaces"",""Region"":""YO""}"
#OR 
$JsonString = Get-Content fromFile.txt

$object = $JsonString | ConvertFrom-Json

$object.Application
$object.'Business Area'
```

[Microsoft Docs on ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7)

Answer (score 1):

An easiest way to do this using .NET class System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer . Microsoft Docs Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
$jsSerializer = New-Object -TypeName System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
$jsSerializer.Deserialize($myjsonstring, 'Hashtable')
```